# Users phoneNumber property is nil after restart

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I verify a user with firebase-auth using the phone provider, the current user has the property phoneNumber filled with the verified number, right after the verification is succeeded.

However, after a restart of the app the property stays empty. I still can get the phone number through the providerData property, but I wonder why the phoneNumber property is not filed anymore.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

code example:

```
var phoneNumber: String? {
    get {
        guard let firUser = firUser else { return nil }
        var phoneNumber: String? = firUser.phoneNumber //filled after verification, but empty after restart
        if phoneNumber == nil {
            for userInfo in firUser.providerData {
                if userInfo.providerID == "phone" {
                    phoneNumber = userInfo.phoneNumber //always filled
                }
            }
        }
        return phoneNumber
    }
}
```

firUser is the current user as I get it from Auth.auth().currentUser

Comment: Show some code that you have tried to fetch property phoneNumber from firebase.

Comment: I added a code example that actually works fine. It's just that the behaviour seems strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

`userInfo.phoneNumber` doesn't exist, you need to check either: `userInfo.uid` or `firUser.phoneNumber`

Comment: Of course it exists (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Protocols/FIRUserInfo), and it works fine.
My point is, that the fireUser.phoneNumber does not work as I expected. Also I just notice that this field is not mentioned in the docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRUser)

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing similar situation where phoneNumber property in UserInfo is populated when user logs in but upon app restart it is nil. To answer your specific question, *Yes this is a bug.*

There is an open issue #67 with Firebase "Phone Auth user not behaving as expected #67" in June'17. It is now closed but since i still seeing the same issue so i am assuming it is not fixed.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/67

There is an alternative solution provided by one of the contributor and which is to get it from provideData object
let phoneNumber = Auth.auth().currentUser!.providerData.first!.phoneNumber!

Above code assumes there is only one provider linked to the user.